# Jquery getJSON not firing callback with valid json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I've got a server that's returning valid json objects (as validated by jsonlint.com) that look like this:

```
"{\"encryption\": {\"key\": \"gKV0oPJwC5CBQxmn\"}}"
```

My html file looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing Jsonp</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='jquery-1.4.4.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='app.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type='text' value='thing' id='target' />
    <a href='' class='init'>Click</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.init').click(function(event){
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:37280/sites/1/encode?callback=?", { key: $("#target").attr('value') }, function(data){
      alert('Success!');
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

When I click on "Click" the Chrome network console indicates that the request is sent, my server logs confirms that the request is received and chrome indicates it receives the above json string. But then nothing happens. I don't get the alert which leads me to believe my callback isn't executing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the response actually returning the quotes around the JSON object? They should not be there.

Comment: Add an error handler and see what it says.

Comment: I've had the server return the string both ways, it does not appear to make a difference in the execution of the callback.

Comment: I noticed when I set the server to return {"encryption": {"key": "gKV0oPJwC5CBQxmn"}} instead of "{"encryption": {"key": "gKV0oPJwC5CBQxmn"}}" the Chrome console throws this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Comment: Also added an error handler which doesn't produce any output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not valid JSON.  JSONLint seems to (newly?) claim that a raw string is valid JSON.  This is not true.  The JSON root must always be an array or object.  RFC 4627 says:

> "A JSON text is a serialized object or
>   array."

Also, you're using JSONP, so you need to include the callback, which you haven't shown in your response.

So if the actual URL is http://localhost:37280/sites/1/encode?callback=jsonp1234

where `jsonp1234` is a function name chosen by jQuery, the response must be:

```
jsonp1234({"encryption": {"key": "gKV0oPJwC5CBQxmn"}});
```

Note that this, like all JSONP, is actually JavaScript.  This is how it can be cross-domain.

Comment: Not including the callback was my mistake. Thanks so much!